# How to replace text values that contain a #

Tags: regex, r, string, text

In my dataset I have a variable with values which contain html-code, e.g.:
`<font color="#800080">None of these</font>`.

I wanted to replace that with `Other` by:

```
df$Country <- gsub("<font color="#800080">None of these</font>", "Other", df$Country)
```

However that doesn't work, which is probably caused by the `#`-character. How can I solve this?

Part of the data:

```
structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Spain", "<font color=\"#800080\">None of these</font>"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Can you give a sample output for df? Also, there are double quotes in your string. You need to escape those. It should be escaped by default when you read it in session.

Comment: Can you post a `dput` if the string to be replace please

Comment: If you are going to match a specific string (and not a pattern) use the `fixed=TRUE` argument in your call to `gsub`. Of course, you need also to escape the quote, as others suggested.

Comment: One option is to escape, the other is to use singe quotes around the pattern to match. Demo: `x <- '<font color="#800080">None of these</font>'; gsub('<font color="#800080">None of these</font>', "other", x); gsub("<font color=\"#800080\">None of these</font>", "other", x)`. But, it might be helpful to actually see a `dput` of what you're actually dealing with.

Comment: I've included a `dput`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanx! Both your solutions worked. If you put that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options to look at. Both assume we are starting with something that looks like this.

```
x <- '<font color="#800080">None of these</font>'
```

1. Option 1: Using a different quote. When you used double quotes to identify your "pattern" argument, it ends at the next double quote it encounters, which comes just before your `#`. Hence, you can try to enclose the pattern with single quotes instead.

   ```
   gsub('<font color="#800080">None of these</font>', "other", x)
   ```
2. Option 2: Escaping the quote character. This is as simple as putting a `\` before the quote to indicate that it should be escaped.

   ```
   gsub("<font color=\"#800080\">None of these</font>", "other", x)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

All these problems with regex on html are reasons not to use it. Assuming your data started out as an actual html document, use XPath instead. Here's an example:

```
html.text <- '<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div><font color="#800080">None of these</font></div>
</body>
<html>'

library(XML)
html <- htmlTreeParse(html.text,useInternalNodes=TRUE)
replaceNodes(html['//font[@color="#800080"]'][[1]],"Other")
# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# <html>
# <head></head>
# <body>
# <div>Other</div>
# </body>
# </html>
```

Comment: The data come from a SPSS-file and this `html` code was in some of the values of some variables. +1 for the nice answer though, I'll might need it for another problem I have to solve :-)